# Trying to get property using Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

i am creating a simple inventory system using larvel 7.i want to join two tables.category and products table.
i ran in to the problem with

```
****Trying to get property  ** '[{"id":1,"product_name":"BoldPen","category":{"id":1,"categoryname":"Pen","created_at":"2021-01-16T16:04:55.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-01-16T16:04:57.000000Z"},"created_at":"2021-01-16T16:06:16.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-01-16T16:06:17.000000Z"},{"id":2,"product_name":"LGTV","category":{"id":3,"categoryname":"Tv","created_at":"2021-01-16T16:05:23.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-01-
of non-object**
```

i am creating a two tables category and products i want have relationship with them.

**Category table**

| id | categoryname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | drink |
| 2 | biscuits |
| 3 | toy |

**product table**

| id | productname | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fanta | 1 |
| 2 | apple juice | 1 |
| 3 | buildblocks | 3 |

i need to category table and product table look like this this and get the data and passing to the table i need this below output

| id | productname | categoryname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fanta | drink |

while i running the program i got the error was

**Trying to get property**

i don't know why it has happing please help me solve problem. what i tried so far i attached below.

Model

Category

```
   class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'categoryname',
    ];

     public function products (){
         return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product','id','category');
     }
}
```

**Product**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_name',
        'category',
    ];

    public function category (){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category','category','id');
    }
}
```

view.blade.php

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($products as $key => $product)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$key}}</td>
        <td>{{$product->product_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$product->category->categoryname}}</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>


**Routes**
Route::get('/products', 'ProductController@view')->name('product.view');
```

**ProductController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Product;
use App\Category;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    
    public function view()
    {
    $products = Product::with('category')->get();
    dd($products);
    $categories = Category::with('products')->get();
    return view ('product.view')-> with([
          'products' -> $products,
           'categories' -> $categories,
    ]);
    }

}
```

Categorytable
[image]

product table
[image]

Screenshot Images
[image]

**Error ScreenShot**
[image]

Comment: Can you please give the screenshots of your Category and Product Tables?

Comment: ok sir.....................................

Comment: Did you saved your Category and Product Models in App\Models directory?

Comment: i attached above two tables screen shot images

Comment: i attached the folder structure screen shots for easy to understand

Comment: there is no Models directory sir. use App/Product ;

Comment: give me the screenshot for the whole error

Comment: i attached above error screen shot

Comment: Controller is there any join fuction join the two tables

Comment: do you have the ability to adjust your schema? as you should not have a relationship named the same as an attribute (field) ... you have a field named `category` and the relationship is `category` which will cause some issues when trying to access that property

Comment: so how can i change as category as catid

Comment: i changed but problem not solved pls help

Comment: where is this error coming from?

Comment: i don't know sir .

Comment: that is why there is also a stacktrace so you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Models directory should be like this.

```
public function category (){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','category','id');
    }

 public function products (){
     return $this->hasMany('App\Product','id','category');
 }
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Product;
use App\Category;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    
    public function view()
    {
    $products = Product::all();
  
    return view ('product.view')->with([
         'products' -> $products
    ]);
    }

}
```

Comment: same code code i paste it same error displayed i attched the screen shot above the full errror

Comment: Controller is there any join fuction join the two tables

Comment: same error displayed i pasted your codes in controller. can you check to the view.blade.php is there any thing to changes

Comment: Your view code is right. You can delete cache and then again check.

Comment: i cleard all cache and i just  ran same error displayed.  join two tables have use $user_with_organization = User::where('id', $user_id)
    ->leftJoin('organizations', 'users.organization_id', '=', 'organizations.id')
    ->select('users.id','organizations.name')->first(); this query

Comment: please help i couldn't solve out the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the error comes from your return view line in your **ProductController**.

```
return view ('product.view')-> with([
      'products' -> $products,
       'categories' -> $categories,
]);
```

It should be

```
return view ('product.view')-> with([
      'products' => $products,
       'categories' => $categories,
]);
```

`->` is trying to access a data inside an object. `=>` is assigning the object into an associative array. With your code, it is trying to access the data inside `'products'` which is not an object.